# Export text from CSV or Excel to Latex document

Tags: csv

Similar to this [creating multiple generic letters from pulling info from an excel/csv file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458904/creating-multiple-generic-letters-from-pulling-info-from-an-excel-csv-file), how can I create multiple files from LaTeX without using r?

I do not have any issues with running LaTeX code multiple times.

Comment: TeX can only make one pdf per run, so you need something to go through the csv file and call TeX multiple times.  r is one option, but any decent programming language would be able to do that.  Which one is your favorite?

Comment: I am a beginner in Python, will it work? or any other?

Comment: Python will be just fine, and shouldn't be too difficult.  You can even follow the R code and the ensuing explanation in the question you linked.  Unfortunately, converting R to Python would be off topic on this site, so if you're having trouble with that, you'll probably need Stackoverflow.  But it's not too bad of a project for a beginner.

Comment: I tried in R, however I get some weird error. I will ask in Stackoverflow